# GitHub Pull Requests with multiple CODEOWNERS approval behavior

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codeowners

In our CODEOWNERS file, we have two groups that are requested to review any changes in a module:

```
# By default, require code-review-board
* @company/code-review-board

module/** @company/module-owners @company/code-review-board
```

In the branch protection rules matching this branch, we [Require a pull request before merging, Require approvals (1 approval), and Require review from Code Owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csg71.png).

When a pull request is opened and someone from module-owners approves the pull request, it is unable to be merged and GitHub says that at least 1 required approval is needed to merge. However, if someone from code-review-board approves, regardless of if anyone from module-owners approves, it is allowed to be merged. How do I allow the PR to be merged when only someone from module-owners approves?